# Open PDF file from media folder Django

Tags: django, pdf

I'm trying to create a link that when click will open a PDF file from my Media folder called tbh_wt_1.pdf.

I've tried:
`<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL}}workouts/tbh_wt_1.pdf"> PDF LINK</a>` but I get a "page not found error"

I've also tried having the PDF "downloaded" with this code:

```
fd = open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'workouts/tbh_wt_1.pdf'))
response = HttpResponse(fd, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=tbh_wt_1.pdf'
return response
```

**Settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR,'media/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

But I get the error "Adobe cannot open file becuase it is not supported"

I appreciate the feedback and expertise.

Comment: Have you set up the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT settings in your settings.py?

Comment: For the first one, are you sure the file exists in that directory, and that something is serving at MEDIA_URL? For her second, you seem to have forgotten to actually open the file, you're just passing the path to HttpResponse.

Comment: I know the file exists as I can attached this file to an email. I've included my MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL from settings.py. I also included "open" but I still get the adobe error. (not sure if I am opening at the correct place). I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write any view code to serve a file that is in the media directory. You should just setup the variables MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py:

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR,'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I assume this problem is happening in a development environment and not in a production server. You should add this lines to your urls.py so that your development server serves this files under the media/ directory.

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

This should be only added to the urls.py for development purposes. For production you should use the options built in web servers such as Apache or Nginx.

The MEDIA_ROOT is used to reference which directory should be served. The MEDIA_URL is used to reference the URL path in the templates.